# Why doesn't RelayCommand RaiseCanExecuteChanged work in a unit test?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm using the current version of MvvmLight available on Nuget (4.1.23.0) and calling RaiseCanExecuteChanged does not appear to be doing anything in a unit test. The scenario is very simple, I have a command:

```
public RelayCommand FooCommand { get; private set; }
```

I new it up in the view model constructor and point it to some private methods:

```
FooCommand = new RelayCommand(Foo, CanFoo);

private void Foo()
{
    // do some fooing.
}

private bool CanFoo()
{
    return SomeRequiredProperty != null;
}
```

Then in the setter for `SomeRequiredProperty` I call RaiseCanExecuteChanged:

```
public object SomeRequiredProperty
{
    get
    {
        return someRequiredProperty;
    }

    set
    {
        someRequiredProperty = value;
        FooCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Now in a unit test I do the following:

```
// Arrange
var canExecuteChanged = false;
viewModel.FooCommand.CanExecuteChanged += (sender, args) => canExecuteChanged = true;

// Act
viewModel.SomeRequiredProperty = new object();

// Assert
Assert.That(canExecuteChanged, Is.True);
```

The test fails because my event handler is not firing. Why is that?

**Update:** The behaviour does indeed work at run time.

Comment: The `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method only calls `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` so it's not directly raising the event. I guess this causes your test to fail, but I don't know how to fix it. During runtime the command is working, am I right?

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thank you. The method name does imply otherwise hey? I'm not at the stage of hooking up the UI to this view model yet, but I did a spike with MvvmLight before choosing frameworks and the CanExecute functionality worked fine.

Comment: Hooked it up quickly to test and updated the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed!

[nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv) was correct in that `FooCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` simply calls `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`.

In addition to that, `FooCommand.CanExecuteChanged` simply forwards the handler on to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add
    {
        ...
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    }
    ... 
}
```

**The cause** of the problem was the following line of code in the [CommandManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.aspx) class:

```
private void RaiseRequerySuggested()
{
    ...
    _requerySuggestedOperation = dispatcher.
        BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new DispatcherOperationCallback(RaiseRequerySuggested),
            null); // dispatcher is the Dispatcher for the current thread.

    ...
}
```

This line places a work item with [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) `Background` on the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) work item queue. The work item is supposed to notify all handlers of the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event.

**The problem** is that this work item is never run.

**The solution** is to force the dispatcher to run the work item.

I found the solution in [this discussion](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/discussions/68127) on the MVVM Foundation CodePlex page. I managed to simplify the code somewhat into the following helper class.

```
public static class DispatcherTestHelper
{
    private static DispatcherOperationCallback exitFrameCallback = ExitFrame;

    /// <summary>
    /// Synchronously processes all work items in the current dispatcher queue.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="minimumPriority">
    /// The minimum priority. 
    /// All work items of equal or higher priority will be processed.
    /// </param>
    public static void ProcessWorkItems(DispatcherPriority minimumPriority)
    {
        var frame = new DispatcherFrame();

        // Queue a work item.
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            minimumPriority, exitFrameCallback, frame);

        // Force the work item to run.
        // All queued work items of equal or higher priority will be run first. 
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }

    private static object ExitFrame(object state)
    {
        var frame = (DispatcherFrame)state;

        // Stops processing of work items, causing PushFrame to return.
        frame.Continue = false;
        return null;
    }
}
```

My test now looks like this:

```
// Arrange
var canExecuteChanged = false;
viewModel.FooCommand.CanExecuteChanged += 
    (sender, args) => canExecuteChanged = true;

// Act
viewModel.SomeRequiredProperty = new object();
DispatcherTestHelper.ProcessWorkItems(DispatcherPriority.Background);

// Assert
Assert.That(canExecuteChanged, Is.True);
```

And, most importantly, it passes :)